# ajax call can't see what's wrong :S

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i click the button to load the js file, nothing happens, i have testet the php file alone without ajax just pure php and that is working! so i am thinking that there's something wrong with this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changePasswordNeededButton').click(function(){
        $.post("http://example.com/change_password.php",
        {
            currentPassword : $('#currentPassword').val(),
            newPassword : $('#newPassword').val(),
            repeatNewPassword : $('#repeatNewPassword').val()
        },
            function(data){
                if (data.result == 1) {
                    location.href = data.location;
                }
            }, "json" // get content which has been returned in json format
        );
    });
});
```

The HTML for this:

```
<div class='changePassword'>
<div id='changePasswordInner'>
    <form>
        <input id='currentPassword' type='password' name='currentPassword' placeholder='Nuværende adgangskode'>
        <input id='newPassword' type='password' name='newPassword' placeholder='Ny adgangskode'>
        <input id='repeatNewPassword' type='password' name='repeatNewPassword' placeholder='Gentag ny adgangskode'>
        <input id='changePasswordNeededButton' type='button' name='changePasswordNeededButton' value='Skift adgangskode'>
    </form>
    <div id'errorChangePassword'></div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../script/change_password.js"></script>
```

And my php:

```
if (isset($_POST['currentPassword']) && isset($_POST['newPassword']) && isset($_POST['repeatNewPassword']) {

    $currentPassword = $_POST['currentPassword'];
    $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $repeatNewPassword = $_POST['repeatNewPassword'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '$currentPassword'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $password = $row['password'];
    }

    if ($password == $currentPassword) {
        $update = "UPDATE user SET password = '$newPassword' WHERE password = '$currentPassword'";
        $db->query($update);
        $result = array(
            'result' => 1,
            'location' => 'index.php',
        );
    }

    // return the result
        echo json_encode($result);
        die();
}
```

I hope that someone can see the error here?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jQuery's $.post documentation to start. I would actually argue using $.ajax instead because of the additional features you get with it; mainly the ability to add callbacks for success and failure.

From jQuery's docs on AJAX:

```
   var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// Add error thrown console.logs here like console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)

    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Comment: Well i just cant see what the error is, this works fine on this other site i am doing. so i just dont het it.. :s I haven't worked much with ajax.

Comment: In the event of a PHP error (if one of the "if" conditions fail), you're not adding any error handling (specifically the SQL). Have you checked the SQL query in something like Sequel Pro or a similar query app?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
'location' => 'index.php',
```

your code is not working for the extra `, at the end of that line`. Since your script is expecting `json` and receiving malformed `json` string.

```
        <?php

    if (isset($_POST['currentPassword']) && isset($_POST['newPassword']) && isset($_POST['repeatNewPassword'])) {



     $result = array(
                'result' => 1,
                'location' => 'index.php'
            );

        echo json_encode($result);

    exit(); 
    };

    ?>

     <form>
            <input id='currentPassword' type='password' name='currentPassword' placeholder='Nuværende adgangskode'>
            <input id='newPassword' type='password' name='newPassword' placeholder='Ny adgangskode'>
            <input id='repeatNewPassword' type='password' name='repeatNewPassword' placeholder='Gentag ny adgangskode'>
            <input id='changePasswordNeededButton' type='submit' name='changePasswordNeededButton' value='Skift adgangskode'>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#changePasswordNeededButton').click(function(){
            $.post("",
            {
                currentPassword : $('#currentPassword').val(),
                newPassword : $('#newPassword').val(),
                repeatNewPassword : $('#repeatNewPassword').val()
            },
                function(data){


                    if (data.result == 1) {
                    location.href=data.location;
                    }


                },"json"
            );
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```